# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tendo problema com esta linha do `javascript`, monto ela dinamicamente pegando dados do `PHP`.

```
fnc_eglise_ajaxGet('ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?d=<?php echo eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD($vinculo->DAT_INICI_VINCU); ?>&p=PV&a=1&pb=<?php echo $w_COD_IDENT_PESSO; ?>&c=<?php echo $vinculo->COD_TIPOX_VINCU; ?>');
```

Ao tentar montar aparece este erro no console do `javascript` e a página não carrega.

> **SyntaxError:** unterminated string literal

O que poderia ser o problema ?

Comment: Provavelmente o valor de `<?php echo eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD($vinculo->DAT_INICI_VINCU); ?>`, `<?php echo $w_COD_IDENT_PESSO; ?>` ou `<?php echo $vinculo->COD_TIPOX_VINCU; ?>` tem um `' ` que está "fechando" a string. Dê uma olhada no código fonte da página no browser, que você terá mais informações sobre o problema.

Comment: A string não foi fechada, pode ser problema na função ou antes/depois desse código.

Comment: Se você está misturando php com javascript, vou pedir-lhe a gentileza de acrescentar a tag php na sua pergunta.

Comment: Uma dica importante: além de misturar códigos, está passando dados para a url. Pense em usar funções como `http_build_query` e `urlencode` do php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigão, eu faria assim para facilitar a visualização das coisas no seu código.

```
printf('fnc_eglise_ajaxGet("ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?%s");', http_build_query(array(
     'd' => $vinculo->DAT_INICI_VINCU,
     'p' => 'PV',
     'c' => $vinculo->COD_TIPOX_VINCU
)));
```

Apesar de alguns criticarem o uso de `sprintf` e `printf`, eu prefiro ter algo que seja mais organizado, e de fácil manutenção e compreensão.

O `http_build_query` vai transformar o `array` do php em dados querystring.

Então, ele transformaria isso:

```
array('nome' => 'Wallace Maxters', 'profissao' => 'Programador PHP')
```

Para isso:

```
nome=Wallace+Maxters&profissao=Programador+PHP
```

Veja o código funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/tLbjAo)

O resultado da minha expressão resultaria na seguinte string em PHP:

```
'fnc_eglise_ajaxGet("ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?d=1&p=PV&c=alguma+coisa");'
```

## PHP e JAVASCRIPT

De acordo com o desejo do autor da pergunta, elaborei como é que o método citado acima seria utilizado juntamente com o javascript desejado pelo mesmo.

Ficaria assim:

```
$('#btnSalvaDelete').click(function () { 
   <?php
        printf('fnc_eglise_ajaxGet("ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?%s");',
            http_build_query(array(
                'd' => $vinculo-> DAT_INICI_VINCU,
                'p' => 'PV',
                'c' => $vinculo-> COD_TIPOX_VINCU,
            )
        )); 
    ?>
 });
```

Comment: Quem criticaria o `sprintf()`? agora ficou clean :D.

Comment: @rray algumas pessoam criticam, falando de performasse. O que adianta diminuir a memória e a legibilidade fazer a manutenção demorar 2 semanas?

Comment: Seu código está dando problema e aparece este erro no console.log: `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`

Comment: No caso entao ficaria assim:         $('#btnSalvaDelete').click(function () {
            printf('fnc_eglise_ajaxGet("ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?%s");', http_build_query(array(
                    'd' = > $vinculo - > DAT_INICI_VINCU,
                    'p' = > 'PV',
                    'c' = > $vinculo - > COD_TIPOX_VINCU
                    )));
        });

Comment: @RenanRodrigues não. Espera aí que vou postar outro `Ideone`.

Comment: Agora foi este erro que deu SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Comment: @RenanRodrigues funcionou? Pois vi que marcou a pergunta.

Comment: Sim funcionou sim

Answer (score 1):

Se você está pegando dados do servidor para criar uma URL, você deve "url-encode" os dados. Por exemplo, se o dado que você está buscando tem um `'`, você vai ter um erro como o que você está recebendo, já que a string será terminada antes que você quer. A função [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) é sua amiga aqui.

```
<?php echo 'fnc_eglise_ajaxGet("ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?d=',
    urlencode(eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD($vinculo->DAT_INICI_VINCU),
    '&p=PV&a=1&pb=',
    urlencode($w_COD_IDENT_PESSO),
    '&c=',
    urlencode($vinculo->COD_TIPOX_VINCU),
    '");' ?>
```

Comment: Talvez resolva o problema, mas ainda sim a legibilidade fica prejudicada.

Comment: Irmão nao funcionou, o netbeans está dando erro na linha final

Answer (score -2):

Olá, tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
fnc_eglise_ajaxGet('ajax\/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?d=<?php echo eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD($vinculo->DAT_INICI_VINCU); ?>&p=PV&a=1&pb=<?php echo $w_COD_IDENT_PESSO; ?>&c=<?php echo $vinculo->COD_TIPOX_VINCU; ?>');
```

Coloquei um escape no /